# Android ScrollView Performance Jellybean 4.2

Tags: android, scrollview

I am running the following layouts on an Android 4.2
When having the buttons in a single LinearLayout everything runs fine:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <Button
            style="@style/auth_primary_button_split"
            android:id="@+id/startup_login"
            android:text="@string/login_label"
            />
    <Button
            style="@style/auth_primary_button_split"
            android:id="@+id/startup_signup"
            android:text="@string/signup_label"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when a wrap the same LinearLayout into a ScrolView, the button clicks are delayed (button background state, onClick function, etc).

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...
</ScrollView>
```

Is this a known issue in Android 4.2?

Comment: haven't noticed anything like this